# Use existing parameters for Transfer SQL Server Objects Task (Initial Catalog missing?)

Tags: ssis

I'm setting up a Transfer SQL Server Objects Task and can't seem to specify existing Connection Managers for it. When parametrizing the Connection Managers it creates, there isn't an Initial Catalog parameter. My package is defined only for server/db/user/password parameters. How can I feed this thing a connection string without making it a parameter of the package? Make a sub-package and pass it a connection? Is there a better way? Maybe use a variable for the connection string parameter somehow?